# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported occurs when calling a delete request

Tags: spring-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4, delete-method

I am trying to implement delete action for the each datatable row by invoking a bootstrap modal. And then sending a delete request to the controller with the parameter of username.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usersTable').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "users/list",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mData": "username"},
            {"mData": "firstName"},
            {"mData": "lastName"},
            {"mData": "status"},
            {"mData": "role.roleName"},
            {
                mRender: function (data, type, row) {

                    var linkDel = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"fillDeleteFrm(\'username\')\">Delete</a>";
                    linkDel = linkDel.replace("id", row.id);
                    linkDel = linkDel.replace("name", row.name);
                    return linkDel;
                }
            }
        ]
    })
});

   function fillDeleteFrm(username) {
    $('#delete-username').val(username);
    $('#userDeleteModal').modal('toggle');
    return false;
}
```

The thymeleaf form that calls the spring controller :

```
        <div id="userDeleteModal">
            <form id="systemUserForm" th:action="@{/userdelete}" th:method="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" id="delete-username" name="username" th:value="*{username}">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The corresponding spring controller :

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/userdelete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@RequestParam String username) {
    User user = userService.findUserByUserName(username);
    userService.deleteUser(user);
    return new ModelAndView("users");
  }
```

Even though I call the delete request method the mapping does not route to this controller, alerting

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

What would I have done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not support `DELETE` method in forms. With `th:method="delete"`, Thymleaf adds a hidden _method form field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

If you add `[HiddenHttpMethodFilter][1]` filter in your application, it will convert the post request to a delete request based on the _method parameter. Try adding the following in your web.xml file.

If you are using spring boot, the filter is automatically included. But in a plain spring web mvc app, you'll have to add the filter manually in web.xml file. This filter is probably missing in your app. That is why the `GET` requested is not being converted to a `DELETE` request.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>     
</filter-mapping>
```